# How to force masonry to use the current/latest css width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

In my css code I have the width option which gets overridden by a second css declaration, the problem is that masonry calculates the positions and the heights based on the first declaration of width which gets overridden anyway when paged has finished loading.

masonry gets loaded with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.entry',
        gutter: 0,
        isAnimated: false
    });
});
```

The problem is clearly not caused by page load order, since I have also tried to load masonry with seTimeout after a minute the page has finished loading, it still uses the first width value but not the last one which is the active one. Since both container and item have different overridden widths, both cause problems with masonry.

Comment: the problem is caused by the fact that js does not grab the correct  witdh, it takes the fixed value for media="all" instead of the active one specified by @media screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by

1 -  $(document).ready() executes before css is loaded correctly, I had to use $(window).load()

2  -  Also some css I defined used selectors actually used by masonry itself which where applied on masonry load therefore it was not picking up the correct values.